# ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209) Unhandled Exception: PlatformException

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I have my flutter App integrated with firebase, everything was fine but after i integrate firebase i got error whenever I try to run my app.
My main method looks like this:

```
Future<void> main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await Firebase.initializeApp(
   options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

 runApp(child: MyApp());
}
```

---

Error:

```
E/flutter ( 7922): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception:
PlatformException(firebase_core, FirebaseApp name [DEFAULT] already exists!, null, null)
E/flutter ( 7922): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope 
(package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter ( 7922): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod 
(package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:177:18)
E/flutter ( 7922): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7922): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod 
(package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:377:43)
E/flutter ( 7922): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7922): #3      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:100:40)
E/flutter ( 7922): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7922): #4      Firebase.initializeApp 
(package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:40:31)
E/flutter ( 7922): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7922): #5      main (package:zunada/main.dart:11:3)
E/flutter ( 7922): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7922):
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when create firebase app by flavors using flutterfire CLI. I realized that flutterfire create apps with same name in different projects. Then I tried 2 ways and it works.

- 1st: manually change app name in each firebase project.
- 2nd: add param name when initialize such as in main_dev.dart

Example:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
 name: "dev-project",
 options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
```

I used the same name used in the firebase console as my project ID for consistency, keep in mind that you cannot add spaces to the name (only dashes -).

Comment: i recieve  "No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()" after inserting the name.....also can u shed more light for the first way